# Apt-get * wildcard with ZSH

Tags: apt, zsh

ZSH:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntuone-* 
ERROR: zsh: no matches found: ubuntuone-*
```

Works on Bash. What's the problem ? :-D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, `zsh` and `bash` behave differently in this regard.

In `zsh`, when you say "`ubuntuone-*`" it looks in your current working directory for files that start with `ubuntuone-` - since it does not find any, it says "`no matches`" and does not run the command.

`bash` takes a different tack - it also looks for files that start with `ubuntuone-` in the current working directory, but if it does not find any it says to itself, "Maybe the program I am invoking knows how to handle the wildcard," and so passes "`ubuntuone-*`" off to `sudo apt-get` as a literal argument.

If you had a file in your current working directory called `ubuntuone-ffdjhjer`, then bash would try to execute `sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntuone-ffdjhjer`, which would probably fail.

In `zsh` (and in `bash`) you can use single quotes to tell it not to expand the wildcard but to pass it on, as in:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge 'ubuntuone-*'
```

Comment: Can I make zsh behave as Bash in that manner?

Comment: I don't know, but the little bit of research I have done so far suggests no. In any case, it is always better (even in bash) to encase arguments in single quotes if you don't want the shell to expand wildcards, because even in bash the command won't do what you want if a file in the CWD matches the wildcard. e.g. I always type `dpkg -l 'linux*'` in bash to see all installed kernels.

Answer (score 14):

Might be a little late this answer, but there is a way to fix this. From command line execute:

```
unsetopt no_match
```

Comment: this works great

Comment: Or `shopt -s failglob` in `bash` to _fix_ `bash` so it behaves like `zsh` and other modern shells like `fish` or `tcsh`  that have fixed that misfeature of the Bourne shell whereby a command may still be run even if the globs didn't match.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yoda

Answer (score 6):

There are another way to prevent expansion in zsh, which i prefer over quotes:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntuone-\*
```